# Is it possible to monitor network activity on Ubuntu Server using existing built-in tools?

Tags: command-line, network-monitoring, tools

There are many utilities that monitor network i/o (bandwidth utilization) such as `iftop`, etc. However none that I'm aware of come packaged in with Ubuntu Server 20.04 cloud image and they need to be installed via Apt.

Is there anything already built into Ubuntu Server 20.04 distro that can monitor network i/o in a similar way to iftop without needing to install any packages?

Comment: define "monitor" - what kind of monitoring are you intending to do?

Comment: Bandwidth utilization in/out of the system. Same type of data as iftop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have `netstat` that display active network connection, also `nethogs` for real time network traffic, `tcpdump` to capture and analyse the content of network traffic, also `ss` for information on sockets connection

Comment: Thanks. nethogs looks perfect but it doesn't appear to be included with Ubuntu Server (at least 20.04), must be installed. Anything else for bandwidth utilization specifically that is built in?

Comment: outside of iftop I dont see other built in tools for this distro